# Stop Teamcity from Auto-Building on Merges in GitHub

Tags: git, github, teamcity

We have a few Builds in Teamcity that take an very long time, and I want to stop them from automatically building on merges into the default branch in GitHub. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this?  Can anyone help me with this, please?

Teamcity 2017.1.4

Comment: Did you check build configuration triggers? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-vcs-triggers.html

Comment: actually it a problem. I just implement the Spring-based services which automatically stop build if have changes.

Comment: Yes I have looked at the documentation.  It says that this is automatic.  I believe that the way to disable this, is to create this automatic trigger, and then disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can Pause the build trigger from action in team city, please the below screenshot for the same.

Click on Action->
[image]